# What's the purpose of the Scala package scala.util.automata?

Tags: parsing, scala, automation, package

I saw the `scala.util.automata` package quite some time ago and just fell over it recently when reading a bit of [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html).

Does anyone have seen this package in usage anywhere yet and for which purpose?

I wonder if those classes have some connection to the parser combinators or if they are used standalone?

The classes have names like

```
class BaseBerrySethi
class DetWordAutom[T <: AnyRef]
trait Inclusion[A <: AnyRef]
class NondetWordAutom[T <: AnyRef]
class SubsetConstruction[T <: AnyRef]
class WordBerrySethi extends BaseBerrySethi
```

and a not very helpful description.

It seems like they will be shipped with Scala 2.9.

Comment: scala.util.automata is now deprecated (since version 2.10.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the implementation of a regular expression to a finite automaton conversion.  http://www2.in.tum.de/hp/file?fid=571 [PDF]  An example of one way to create an NDFA can be found at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/regexp/WordExp.html, although that doesn't show how to use the resulting automaton.  It appears the automaton would be used by calling "next" repeatedly, threading the state set in the form of a BitSet through and checking each time with containsFinal to see if the automaton had reached a final state. What I don't see is what the initial states should be represented as, but it would seem likely that the initial state would be an empty BitSet.

Comment: Do you know of any examples of their use?

Comment: Updated my answer with a link of an example and some discussion.

Comment: It converts all the way to DFA, actually.

Comment: It looks like the API can do either.  The example I posted does happen to be an NDFA, but I'll update my answer.

Comment: The initial state is always 0. There was a time when Scala's pattern matching included regular expressions, then it was retracted http://www.scala-lang.org/node/122 -- the compiler was using these algorithms, and it seemed useful to expose them as a library. I still think it is a useful library.

Answer (score 1):

It was one of the first things I came upon when I started learning Scala. Found some bugs in it, too. It isn't particularly useful, and there was even some discussion about deprecating it.

It does implement a fairly flexible algorithm to convert regular expressions all the way to DFAs, but the DFA itself isn't particularly flexible, iirc.

Comment: What's inflexible about it?  It looks like you can pass arbitrary state sets in, even ones that can't possibly happen given your machine description.

Comment: @James Well, it's been two years, but I faintly recall not being able to extend the DFA as to add stuff to states and/or transitions, which were required by the application I had in mind.